# PyBlueZ causes errors on import

Tags: python, python-3.5, pybluez

I am attempting to write a program that can pair to a game console via bluetooth and act as a controller for it. In order to do this, I have tried to install PyBlueZ, but I can get no further than `import bluetooth`, because it displays this error on my screen:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import bluetooth
  File "C:\Python35\lib\bluetooth\__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    from bluetooth.msbt import *
  File "C:\Python35\lib\bluetooth\msbt.py", line 2, in <module>
    import bluetooth._msbt as bt
ImportError: No module named 'bluetooth._msbt'
```

Is this because of an error in my installation, or is the module just broken? In either case, is there a fix?

Comment: it looks like it hasn't been fully installed, or installed in wrong directrories

Comment: Which directory should it be installed in?

Comment: I don't know specifically, because  I haven't used it before, but it should probably all be in the same directory as itself, and it is, while not always necessary, a safe bet to put it in the same directory as your program.